# Let $L$ and $M_c: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R ^3$ be linear transformations. Find $c \in \mathbb R$ such that Im $L =$ Im $M_c$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have tried solving the exercise of a workbook on linear algebra I'm following, but my solution doesn't correspond with the one provided at the end of the text. Both my theory and practice books are in Italian, so I had to translate the problem assignment into English, and there is the possibility I will be using some notation in a different way than it is done on this site (although I find this unlikely).

Let $L: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation such that:

$$L(e_1) = e_1 + e_3, \quad L(e_2) = 2e_1 + 2e_2 + 3e_3, \quad L(e_3) = 3e_1 + 2e_2 + 4e_3,$$

and for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ let $M_c: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the only linear transformation such that:

$$M_c \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = ce_1 + 2e_2 + 2e_3, \quad M_c \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = 2e_2 + ce_3.$$

Find 1. for what $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\mathrm{Im}\ L = \mathrm{Im}\ M_c$, and 2. calculate the dimension of $\mathrm{Im}\ L \cap \mathrm{Im}\ M_c$ for all the values of $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

As I was unable to find a correct solution to problem 1., I didn't proceed to the other. Below is my attempt at solving only the first point:

My theory book contains a very useful lemma. Here is its statement:

> **Lemma 5.6**
>
> Let $T: V \to W$ be a linear transformation, and $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ a basis for $V$. Therefore $\mathrm{Im}T = \mathrm{Span}(T(v_1), ..., T(v_n))$.

Given that $B_L = \{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ is the only set of vectors for which $L$ is defined, and also the standard basis of $\mathbb{R^3} = \mathrm{Dom}(L)$, due to **Lemma 5.6** I can conclude that:

$$\mathrm{Im} L = \mathrm{Span}(L(e_1), L(e_2), L(e_3)) = \mathrm{Span}(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 2 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}).$$

And observing that:

$$1 \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} + 1 \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 2 \\ 4\end{pmatrix},$$

the three vectors are linearly dependent, and so:

$$\mathrm{Im}L = \mathrm{Span}(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 2 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}) = \mathrm{Span}(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}).$$

Now, even $M_c$ is explicitly defined for two inputs, and they also form (don't they?) a basis for the domain of $M_c$:

$$\mathrm{Span}(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}) = \mathbb{R}^2;$$

therefore, even in this case I can simply state that:

$$\mathrm{Im}M_c = \mathrm{Span}(M_c\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}, M_c\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}) = \mathrm{Span}(\begin{pmatrix}c \\ 2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2 \\ c\end{pmatrix}).$$

This gave me the (almost naive) idea of setting up a system between the images of the two transformations, and study it according to the variations of $c \in \mathbb{R}$. I'll save you some boring calculations and leave you with the initial and final state (reduced echelon form) of the system:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -c & 0 \\0 & 2 & -2 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 & -2 & -c\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -c & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & c - 2 & -2 \\0 & 0 & 2 - c & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$

After this I switched to a brackets system and, for some reasons I'm sparing right now, the only plausible solution was $c = 2$, even though the book says that $c = 1$.

This problem already subtracted me substantial time (even in writing this question), and even if no teacher or assignment is requiring me to complete it, I would still like doing it. As for why I haven't yet solved it, I think I must have overlooked some (perhaps highly) trivial detail: this problem doesn't look very difficult.

---

Solution supplied from the workbook:

> $\mathrm{Im}\ L = \mathrm{Im}\ M_c$ if and only if $c = 1$; in such a case $\dim(\mathrm{Im}\ L \cap \mathrm{Im}\ M_c) = 2$. If $c \neq 1$, the dimension of $\mathrm{Im}\ L \cap \mathrm{Im}\ M_c$ is always equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the images of the two linear maps correctly. Both range subspaces are spanned by the two vectors you said. Since the ranges must be equal, every vector in the range of $M_c$, say $(c, 2, 2)$ must be a linear combination of $(1, 0, 1)$ and $(2, 2, 3)$. Solve this system to get $c = 1$.